# Delete file longer then 30 days old for long path and long file name

Tags: windows, command-line, batch-file, scheduled-tasks

I tried to make batch file in windows by using task schedule once a month to find *.bak. With condition more then 30 old. I create two condition full path name and non-8dot3 path name. For those unable to delete it be recorded to a TXT file.

Here the command I found:

```
forfiles /P E:\WP /S /M *.bak /D -30 /C "cmd /C del @path"
```

Here is my command for delete using non-8dot3 file names:

```
forfiles /P E:\WP /S /M *.bak /D -30 /C "cmd /C for %A in (@path) do @echo del %~sA
```

For file can't be delete because it to long path and file name, it recorded to a TXT file with long full path file name and non-8dot3:

```
forfiles /P E:\WP /S /M *.bak /D -30 /C "cmd /c echo @path >> list.txt"
forfiles /P E:\WP /S /M *.bak /D -30 /C "cmd /c for %A in (@path) do @echo %~sA" >> list.txt
```

These 4 command are working well if I just copy and paste into dos command prompt.

But when I put them into batch file e.g. "del30days.bat", it does not working for non-8dot3 file names:

```
@echo off
:: Set host computer name
set host=%COMPUTERNAME%

:: Set save list path
set list_path=F:\LogFiles

:: Set min age of files and folders to delete
set file_list=ListCantDeleted-%host%-%date:~10,4%-%date:~7,2%-%date:~4,2%.txt

:: Set target folder path
set target_path=E:\WP

:: Set min age of files and folders to delete
set max_days=30

:: Set what kind files or extension
set file_ext=*.bak

:: Delete files from target path
forfiles /P %target_path% /S /M %file_ext% /D -%max_days% /C "cmd /C del @path"
forfiles /P %target_path% /S /M %file_ext% /D -%max_days% /C "cmd /C for %A in (@path) do @echo del %~sA"


:: Record files from target path
forfiles /P %target_path% /S /M %file_ext% /D -%max_days% /C "cmd /c echo @path >> %list_path%\%file_list%"
forfiles /P %target_path% /S /M %file_ext% /D -%max_days% /C "cmd /C for %A in (@path) do @echo %~sA >> %list_path%\%file_list%"
```

I got this error on non-8dot3 files name but not on long file name on record to a TXT file, by mean it can't delete file using non-8dot3 file names as well.

```
~sA" was unexpected at this time.
```

Any reason why?

The goal I create this is to delete *.bak file more then 30 days without any issue on long path and file name. Anyone got simplify solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

You're going to slap yourself.  The problem is that in a batch file, for loop variables need a double percent.  %%A and %%~sA.